# How to use ip address from Dhcp on Docker containers

Tags: docker, dhcp

I am trying to assign an Ip address to docker container using dhcp. Has anyone used dhcp to assign ip address to docker containers on rhel/ubuntu?
Any help would be appreciated. I couldn't find any proper documentation for this.
Thanks

Comment: Usually you don't, any more than you'd want to assign a dedicated IP address for the ssh daemon on your host.  You'd use `docker run -p` to assign a port on your host and then access the container using that port number and the host's IP address or DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you revisit your issue, most probably there is a better way to do this.

If not you can try macvlan as discribed [here](https://gist.github.com/nerdalert/3d2b891d41e0fa8d688c).

Comment: I saw the link and I am struck at first step which says "Download the driver compiled into Docker Engine ". I downloaded the binary. Where should I copy that driver to now? and do I have to do anything (compile) before I copy it to some location?

Comment: I copied the plugin to all the below locations: "/run/docker/plugins/", "/usr/lib/docker/plugins/", "/var/lib/docker/plugins", "/etc/docker/plugins" and restarted docker. I get the below error: "Error response from daemon: plugin not found"

Comment: @Premchand the compiled code is the whole docker binary, u need to replace your docker binary with that